# (Batch) moving iTunes songs to ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Artist/SongName

Tags: itunes, time-machine, music

I have three albums by *Jack Singer*. They are in ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/**Jack Singer/SongName**.

I also have one album by *Jack Singer and his band*. Those files are in ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/**Jack Singer and his band/SongName**

I choose to ignore the distinction and rename the artist of the latter to become just *Jack Singer*. iTunes does not move the files. They remain where they are. Presumably this is done to avoid unnecessary Time Machine changes. But I would like to move the files to their canonical location before launching my first Time Machine backup after adding the new album.

How do I tell iTunes to move the files to ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/**Jack Singer/SongName**, mirroring the name of the artist in the tag?

Comment: My iTunes 10.6.3 moves the files instantly, so I don't think there are Time Machine considerations here. In the Preferences -> Advanced, is the iTunes Library path correct? Are the 2 next checkboxes checked?

Comment: This is indeed the answer. Please add it as such. (Under Preferences \ Advanced, "Keep iTunes media folder organized" must be checked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments: Under Preferences -> Advanced, "Keep iTunes media folder organized" must be checked